# Have MS published an EOL date for IE11 mode in Edge?

Tags: internet-explorer, eol

IE11 as a product is End-Of-Life'ing. Hurray. My understanding is that IE-11 mode in MS Edge uses the IE11 (Trident) rendering engine to maintain compatibility for old sites/applications. That's a Windows component though, not the IE11 product.

Given this, has MS released any dates for when IE11 mode will be supported/available for and what's going to happen to the rendering engine (fixes? support?) once the IE11 product is gone?

Answer (score 0):

The [IE mode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/deployedge/edge-ie-mode#:%7E:text=What%20is%20IE%20mode%3F,(IE11)%20for%20legacy%20sites.) is a feature of the **MS Edge** browser and it will continue to work after the **IE 11** browser gets discontinue in the future.

Microsoft has not released any EOL date for the **IE mode** feature for the Edge browser.